# Regular Expression to Match string pattern followed by N digits in snowflake

Tags: string, substring, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, string-matching

I have dataset like below in table A and I want result-set where the pattern for value column is like ABC followed by any 8 digits.

[image: Table A]

Output should be like below after regex match

[[image: Table B2]

I tried to use regex_sbustr but failed to get actual result set for 8 digits pattern.

Will appreciate your help

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE(value, 'ABC[0-9]{8}.*')` based on your sentence. BUT... Why is `ABC876hjkl90` in your desired results? That's not "ABC" followed by 8 digits.

Comment: @JNevill You are right. I apologies for that. I corrected  the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And to show @JNevil's [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/regexp_like.html) solution working:

```
select 
    column1, 
    column2, 
    REGEXP_LIKE(column2, 'ABC[0-9]{8}.*') as match
from values
    (1, 'ABC123456788999'),
    (2, 'ABC123458765uhfh=hh'),
    (3, 'BCA123456788999'),
    (4, 'ABC987654321'),
    (5, 'ABC876hjkl90'),
    (6, 'ABC876');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123456788999 | TRUE |
| 2 | ABC123458765uhfh=hh | TRUE |
| 3 | BCA123456788999 | FALSE |
| 4 | ABC987654321 | TRUE |
| 5 | ABC876hjkl90 | FALSE |
| 6 | ABC876 | FALSE |

thus in filtering form:

```
select 
    column1, 
    column2 as value
from values
    (1, 'ABC123456788999'),
    (2, 'ABC123458765uhfh=hh'),
    (3, 'BCA123456788999'),
    (4, 'ABC987654321'),
    (5, 'ABC876hjkl90'),
    (6, 'ABC876')
where REGEXP_LIKE(column2, 'ABC[0-9]{8}.*');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123456788999 |
| 2 | ABC123458765uhfh=hh |
| 4 | ABC987654321 |

As per the documents, the LIKE version is automatically anchored, which means there is an implicit `^` and `$` added to the begin/end of you regexp string, thus the need for the `.*` in this solution, otherwise none of the given input will match, as they all have 9 or more tokens.

as seen here (with extra 8 numeric input):

```
select 
    column1, 
    column2, 
    REGEXP_LIKE(column2, 'ABC[0-9]{8}') as match
from values
    (1, 'ABC123456788999'),
    (2, 'ABC123458765uhfh=hh'),
    (3, 'BCA123456788999'),
    (4, 'ABC987654321'),
    (5, 'ABC876hjkl90'),
    (6, 'ABC876'),
    (8, 'ABC12345678')
    ;
```

| COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 | MATCH |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC123456788999 | FALSE |
| 2 | ABC123458765uhfh=hh | FALSE |
| 3 | BCA123456788999 | FALSE |
| 4 | ABC987654321 | FALSE |
| 5 | ABC876hjkl90 | FALSE |
| 6 | ABC876 | FALSE |
| 8 | ABC12345678 | TRUE |

Comment: @Simoen thanks for the solution. If I need ABC to be insensitive

Comment: By reading the attached help page and noting the third optional parameter and using the`‘i’` value.